# How to access dom js from contentjs manifest

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I'm developing a chrome extension , my intention is

```html
<button id="j_id_ae" name="j_id_ae" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" aria-label="" onclick="fscr();PF('fscrDlg').hide();" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Go Full Screen</span></button>
```

call the function PF('fscrDlg') when ever the button appears on the screen

```js
function checkForChanges() {
    console.log("hello");
    let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    if(buttons){
        for(let i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++){
            if(buttons[i].innerText.includes('Go Full Screen')){
                PF('fscrDlg').hide();
            }
        }
    }
}
setInterval(checkForChanges, 1000);
```

This is my content.js but the error says function PF is not defined however when I run the function in chrome console it's working fine. How to access the dom js from content js in manifest v3

I tried different methods like changing the onlick of the button and then pressing on the button like

```js
buttons[i].onclick = PF('fscrDlg').hide();
buttons[i].click();
```

but this isn't changing the dom.